# Trying to understand IP5306 battery manager

Tags: batteries, charger, power-management

The manufacturers [datasheet](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1139129/Injoinic/IP5306/1) of the IP5306 Battery manager IC doesn't explicitly explain how the charger works. I would like to know from which pin of the IC goes out the current to charge the battery cell.

Comment: And I say you're wrong, see page 2 of the datasheet (which would be a good thing to link to in the question).

Comment: Page 2 of the datasheet says: Pin 6 (BAT): Battery voltage sense pin. From this I understand it is an input pin. Pin 7 (SW): DCDC switch mode, connect inductor. From that I understand it is an input pin for the boost converter. That is for the discharge mode. It will use the battery source to boost its voltage in order to provide the 5 volt to the USB/A ports. Pin 8 (VOUT): DCDC 5 V output pin. I understand it should be connected to the USB/A ports. The other pins cant be outputs to charge the battery cell. Please help me understand which pin should provide the current to charge the battery.

Answer (score 1):

The [datasheet](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1139129/Injoinic/IP5306/1) is in my opinion poorly written. It mentions (SW) @ Pin 7 **BAT** in a couple of places:

Page 2 - *1 Simplified application schematic*
Page 9 - *Typical Application Schematic*

There's no mention of **BAT** in connection to any other pin which leaves us to the conclusion that pin 7 is the charging pin *as well as* the input pin.

Well actually there is. And here is why I think the datasheet is not up to standard: Pin 6 is named BAT, despite it's function to *sense* the battery's voltage - see *2 IP5306 Pin Diagram*, pin 6. So some badly chosen names for a couple of pins can be misleading.

If this isn't enough to convince you, why don't you have a look at other schematics that are published on the internet?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was a bit confused when you suggested that the pin SW could both be used as input and output, because I am not used to this. But it seems there is not other possibility left for this chip to provide sourcing current to charge the battery cell. I find this chip has many interesting and advanced features but it's a pity the manufacturer did't provide enough detailed information about how the chip works internally. Ones more I thank you for your answer.

Comment: Thank you, and don't forget to mark the answer as the solution if you think it deserves so. And those Chinese datasheets can be tricky, if you compare with such chip suppliers like TI, Onsemi, NXP etc.